# SQL Query to see all productName and which category its belong

Tags: mysql

So I have a task all I need to do is to write Query to
select all the product names and which category they belong to.

I Using the tables from W3SCHOOL - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

I Would like to know why this Query -

```
SELECT p.ProductName
     , c.CategoryName
  From Products p
  Join Categories c
    ON p.ProductID = c.CategoryID
```

not working for me, it gives me only 8 Products with 8 different category names and I need all of the products name from each category.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is almost correct, you are joining on the wrong column,

```
SELECT Products.ProductName, Categories.CategoryName
FROM Products
JOIN Categories ON Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID
```

should do.

Comment: Can you explain what did you do ? i dont understand the syntax you using

Comment: Or if you can just write the full syntax without the shortcuts ( p,c)

Comment: When i replacing the p with Products its sending an error..

Comment: I just name aliased tables (less code), you can replace p with Products and it should be fine. JOIN is same as INNER JOIN in MYSQL syntax (you can replace it with "INNER JOIN"). Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your `join` query 
You are joining ***Products.ProductID*** when you should join ***Products.CategoryID***

The correct query should be as the following:

```
SELECT p.ProductName, c.CategoryName
FROM Products p
JOIN Categories c ON p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
```